# running wireshark "Lua: Error during loading"

Tags: wireshark, lua

By running wireshark in 14.04 I got this error What should I do to solve this?

Lua: Error during loading:
 [string "/usr/share/wireshark/init.lua"]:46: dofile has been disabled due to running Wireshark as superuser. See http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges for help in running Wireshark as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is because (I presume) you are running wireshark as root

From the link you were given in the message:

> You need to run Wireshark or TShark on an account with sufficient privileges to capture, or need to give the account on which you're running Wireshark or TShark sufficient privileges to capture. The way this is done differs from operating system to operating system.
>
> **To be secure (at least in a way), it is recommended that even an administrator should always run in an account with (limited) user privileges, and only start processes that really need the administrator privileges.** The Security page provides explanations why this is a good idea.
>
> Setting network privileges for dumpcap
>
> 1. Ensure your linux kernel and filesystem supports File Capabilities and also you have installed necessary tools.
> 2. "setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap"
> 3. Start Wireshark as non-root and ensure you see the list of interfaces and can do live capture.

so ...

```
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

don't forget to add the user to the wireshark group

```
sudo usermod -aG wireshark $USER
```

and **(!)** logo-off and log-on again.
Then run wireshark as a non-root user.

Comment: Yes, I run that with sudo.

Comment: I wrote this :  sudo "setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap" and I got this : sudo: setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap: command not found

Comment: try `sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap`

Comment: There is some documentation  in the folder: /usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/
  in a readme file. It goes on about some other non-root options, and dependencies for other tasks you may wish to complete.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple fix for this.

1. Go to `usr/share/wireshark`.
2. Open `init.lua` with a text editor.
3. Change `disable_lua = false` to `disable_lua = true`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you didn't add user to wireshark group, So:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Say YES to the message box.This adds a wireshark group.Then add user to the group by typing

```
sudo adduser $USER wireshark
```

Then restart your machine and open wireshark.

Run

```
wireshark
```

and it works good luck ;)

by @Thusitha Sumanadasa

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mint (based on Ubuntu), in my case, it's the location of the output file caused the issue, when I change the output file to under `/tmp/`, then the issue is solved.

e.g

- `tshark -i wlp7s0 -w /tmp/a.pcap`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to open `/usr/share/wireshark/init.lua` in a text editor:

```
nano /usr/share/wireshark/init.lua
```

There you'll see a line similar to this:

```
 enable_lua = true
```

Make it look like

```
 enable_lua = false
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit.

Wireshark is ready to use!