# What is 'setcap' command and 'file capability'?

Tags: command-line, setcap

What is the `setcap`command and what is `file capability`, also the meaning of below "setcap output:

```
CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip "/usr/bin/dumpcap"
```

[Running Wireshark - "Lua: Error during loading"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454734/running-wireshark-lua-error-during-loading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link you provided , the use `setcap`  Sniffing with Wireshark as a Non-Root User because, by default, raw access to network interfaces (e.g. eth0) requires root privileges and running it with root privileges is a bad idea  .

setcap - set file capabilities

man page [Link](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap)

Check file system capabilities [Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)

```
CAP_NET_ADMIN - Allow various network-related operations (e.g., setting privileged socket options, enabling multicasting, interface configuration, modifying routing tables).



CAP_NET_RAW - Permit use of RAW and PACKET sockets.
```

For more info [Site](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/)