# How to enable Wireshark without running as root in Trusty 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, wireshark

I installed Wireshark. Running as root is not recommended, so

I Did

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

According to:

http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges

http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/collab-maint/ext-maint/wireshark/trunk/debian/README.Debian?view=markup

Answered Yes,
Logout out
Started Wireshark and got this message:

```
couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: Permission Denied.
```

I think I followed the recommended way of configuring Wireshark, it worked in 13.10, it doesn't in 14.04

FYI, reconfiguring wireshark-common is actually setting the group for dumpcap to Wireshark. Still it doesn't work. I checked that.

How should it be done in 14.04?

Comment: I guess you've already checked that you, the user, are in the wireshark group

Comment: Yes. that said, I stumble on this

    `groups $USER`

does list wireshark

    `groups $user` 

does NOT list wireshark

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run wireshark, with root-privileges?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges)

Comment: Simply run this: sudo usermod -aG wireshark $USER. Then, log out and back in again.

Answer (score 81):

I found that after running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

a `wireshark` group been created in `/etc/gshadow`. So I just wrote:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER wireshark
```

and logout/login and now it works fine!

Comment: Three cheers. This should be marked as the solution but OP probably abandoned the thread.

Comment: Instead of logout/login, just type `newgrp wireshark` as your normal user, it is faster, and works the same in my experience with 18.04.

Comment: Yeah it works, can you please explain above commands in detail, or can provide any link?

Comment: Works 101% Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you did correct. But some thing is missing.If you see the error message like `couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: Permission Denied`.Go to terminal and

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

choose answer as "`YES`" .Then add user to the group by

```
sudo adduser $USER wireshark
```

Then restart your machine and open wireshark. It works.

Comment: You don't have to restart. Logging out/in would do.

Comment: Don't forget to add the "-a" parameter to the adduser command.

`-a, --add USER                add USER to GROUP`

Comment: I had to restart - login/out did not work (ubuntu 16.10-64bit)

Comment: Yeah it works, can you please explain above commands in detail, or can provide any link?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

[Check this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454734/running-wireshark-lua-error-during-loading)

Comment: Now I can see all the Interfaces, but the error messages still showing up when the program is starting.